# Delete option 'None' of the select list of a cck field

Tags: entities

How can I delete the option -None- of the select list in a cck field.  The field is not required.

Comment: Do you want to delete it and so there's no more "empty" option (which is what keithm suggested) or to you want to rename it ?

Comment: CCK will always provide the None option for a select field unless it is required.

Comment: I need to delete the option "none" of the select list in a cck field with select list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a module and used `form_alter` hook to remove the `None` value of a CCK select list:

```
<?php

function MODULENAME_form_alter($form, &$form_state) {
    //dsm($form['form_id']['#id']); //dsm() used for see the ID of form
    if ($form['form_id']['#id'] == 'edit-test-content-type-node-form') {
      $form['#after_build'][] = 'change_form_values_after_build'; //call to a function
    }
}

function change_form_values_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  $new_array = array();
  $new_array = array('Yes' => 'Yes','No' => 'No');
  $form['field_test_select_list']['value']['#options'] = $new_array;
  return $form;
}
```

In this case, I have used the function `change_form_values_after_build` (introduced by `#after_build`) to introduce the desired values in an array, but I guess that you can make a database query, to retrieve the options that you have added in the interface of field, and remove the undesired value, to return again to the form the array with correct values.

I hope information be useful.

Comment: It's a good alternative, it works for me.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Make the field *required* in Global Settings.

Comment: This is correct. If the field is not required, the list of values for a select field should contain a value that is selected when the user doesn't want to enter any value.

Comment: The field IS NOT REQUIRED.  I need to delete or change the option -None- by 'Please choose'.

If the field is not required, i need that the value selected by the user when the user doesn't want to enter any value be "Please choose".